# Can anyone recognize what kind of 3D plotting function does this? (MATLAB)

Tags: image, matlab, 3d, plot

I have written a code for SAFT (Synthetic Aperture Focusing Technique) and successfully plotted 2D images. Now, I have a problem in plotting it in 3D because I have no idea what kind of function should I use. I want to create the 3D image as shown in the image link below (the right one with solid volume) but i have no idea about the function they have used. All I know is that the left image was made by splice.

I would really appreciate if anyone can help me about this problem. Thank you in advance!

[image: 3D plots]

Here's a sample code I've been using for the 3D array. Note that I just used random values for the intensity, V here since the real values are stored in excel files. I'm getting an error when using isosurface since my arrays are not created using meshgrid.

```
r=linspace(50,500,101)';
o=zeros(101,1);
X=zeros(51,101,13);
Y=zeros(51,101,13);
Z=zeros(51,101,13);
V=rand(size(X));

slice=1;
for angle=0:15:180
    for elev=1:1:51
    %Setup X,Y,Z Coordinates
        X(elev,:,slice)=(r*cos(angle*3.141593/180))';
        Y(elev,:,slice)=(r*sin(angle*3.141593/180))';
        Z(elev,:,slice)=(o+((elev-1)*0.01))';
    end 
if slice < 13
    slice=slice+1;
else
end
end
```

Comment: have you tried 'isosurf'?

Comment: thanks, i'll try to study how it works

Comment: It takes a 3d array f and a value v as inputs and shows the surface of f=v

Comment: will it still work if the coordinate array is not formed using meshgrid? my coordinates are cylindrical so i can't use the meshgrid command.

Comment: If you'll post a link to your data I can try for you.

Comment: thanks! i edited the post and included the sample code for the 3D array. I did not include anymore the intensity values since it is imported from excel files so i just put random values.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try 'surf' or 'mesh'? Don't know if it will work for your case, but give it a try.

Comment: Ok i tried using 'isosurf' but i got an error saying my matrices should be produced by 'meshgrid'. So i think using 'mesh' wont work too. The size of my matrices are 73x101x11.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is to use the matlab function `isosurface`. The only problem is that your grid is not Cartesian.
You should create a Cartesian grid using `meshgrid` and resample your `V` values to that grid before using `isosurface` to display the results.

Comment: Oh :( I can't resample my 'V' values to a cartesian grid because it is locked to the cylindrical coordinates. Even if i create a mesh grid that has coordinates equal or close to the cylindrical coordinates (which will result to a very fine mesh = more points), it will be very hard for me to assign the 'V' values to their corresponding coordinates.